# How to replace english abbreviated form to their dictionary form

Tags: dictionary, text, nlp, token, cpu-word

I'm working on a system to analyze texts in english: I use stanford-core nlp to make sentences from whole documents and to make tokens from sentences. I also use the maxent tagger to get tokens pos tags. 
Now, considering that I use this corpus to build a supervised classifier, it would be good if I could replace any word like 're, 's, havin, sayin', etc. to its standard form(are, is, having, saying). I've been searching for some english dictionary file, but I don't know how to use it. There are so many distinct cases to consider that I don't think it's an easy task to realize: is there some similar work or whole project that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

I) use string edit distance on a subset of your text and try to match words that do not exist in the dictionary using edit distance against existing words in the dictionary.

II) The key feature of lots of those examples you have is that they are only 1 character different from the correct spelling. So, I suggest for those words that you fail to match with a dictionary entry, try and add all english characters to the front or back and lookup the resulting word in a dictionary. This is very expensive in the beginning but if you keep track of those misspellings in a lookup table (re -> are) at some point you will have 99.99% of the common misspellings (or whatever you call them) in your lookup table with their actual correct spelling.

III) Train a word-level 2-gram or 3-gram language model on proper and clean english text (i.e. newspaper articles), then run it over the entire corpus that you have and see for those words that your language model considers as unknown words (which means it hasn't seen them in training phase), what is the highest probable word according to the language model. Most probably the language model top-10 prediction will be the correct spelled word.